Closed form of $\int_{(0,1)^5} \frac{xyuvw}{(1-(1-xy)u)(1-(1-xy)v)(1-(1-xy)w))}\, dx\,dy\,du\,dv\,dw$
I need closed form for the integral $$I:=\int_{(0,1)^5} \frac{xyuvw}{(1-(1-xy)u)(1-(1-xy)v)(1-(1-xy)w))} \, dx\,dy\,du\,dv\,dw$$
Then $$0<I<\int_{(0,1)^5} \frac{1}{(1-(1-xy)u)(1-(1-xy)v)(1-(1-xy)w))} \,dx\,dy\,du\,dv\,dw$$
So $$0<I<\int_{(0,1)^2} \frac{-\log^3(xy)}{(1-xy)^3} \, dx\,dy$$
By Wolfram alpha
$$0<I<27.4126$$
So the given integral converges. How do we find a closed form of this integral may be in terms of Riemann zeta function? Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Do you have any reason to believe that this should have a closed form?

The integrals for $u,v,w$ can be seperately evaluated as
$$
\int_0^1\frac{u}{1-u (1-x y)}\,du=-\frac{1-x y+\ln (x y)}{(1-x y)^2}
$$
Now let
$$
f(z)=-z\left(\frac{1-z+\log (z)}{(1-z)^2}\right)^3
$$
we get
$$
I=\int_0^1\int_0^1 f (x y)\,dxdy=\int_0^1 f (z)\log(1/z)\,dz=\int_0^1 z\left(\frac{1-z+\log (z)}{(1-z)^2}\right)^3\log (z)\,dz
$$
Antiderivative can be directly found, and
$$
I=\frac{\zeta (3)}{2}+\frac{\pi^2}{8}-\frac{\pi^4}{75}-\frac{17}{120}
$$

Very nice ! Simple moreover ....(after reading the solution).

How did you "directly" get the antiderivative? According to Wolfram Alpha it starts (with about 600 more characters that won't fit in a comment)
integral z ((1 - z + log(z))/(1 - z)^2)^3 log(z) dz = (-144 z^5 Li_4(z) + 720 z^4 Li_4(z) - 1440 z^3 Li_4(z) + 1440 z^2 Li_4(z) - 720 z Li_4(z) + 144 Li_4(z) - 6 (z - 1)^5 Li_2(z) (12 log^2(z) + 10 log(z) - 15) + 12 (z - 1)^5 Li_3(z) (12 log(z) + 5) - 54 z^5 + 6 z^5 log^4(z) + 10 z^5 log^3(z) - 24 z^5 log(1 - z) log^3(z) - 45 z^5 log^2(z) - 30 z^5 log(1 - z) log^2(z) + 90 z^5 log(1 - z) log(z) + 276 z^4 - 30 z^4 log^4(z) - 74 z^4 log^3
